# ARRAY_AGG gives error 'operator does not exist: text ->> unknown'

Tags: json, postgresql

I get this error

> ERROR:  operator does not exist: text ->> unknown

When i run

```
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(data->>'promotion_data' || '-' || data->>'id')
  FROM data.persons
GROUP BY data->>'store_id'
```

but this works

```
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(data->>'promotion_data' || '-')
  FROM data.persons
GROUP BY data->>'store_id'
```

I tried to cast to json, but still the same error:

```
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(data->>'promotion_data' || '-' || data::json->>'id')
  FROM data.persons
GROUP BY data->>'store_id'
```

Comment: What PostgreSQL version is that?

Comment: Solved by a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 1):

Use parentheses:

```
ARRAY_AGG((data->>'promotion_data') || '-' || (data->>'id'))
```

The `||` seems to have a higher priority than the `->>` operator.

Alternatively you can use `concat_ws()`

```
ARRAY_AGG(concat_ws(',', data->>'promotion_data', data->>'id'))
```

Comment: Strange - the precedence is `->>` before `||` in all versions I have here (9.4 upwards).